# Optional Where Clause Based On Another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored proc where a table of integers is passed as a parameter.  I'm trying to find a reasonable way of writing "give me all the records, but if the parameter table has values in it then limit my results to those values".

Both approaches in the queries below work, but when I use either approach in my real-world proc (with a substantial number of joins and apply clauses and a ton of data) it's quite a bit slower than I would like even when the number of rows in the variable table is limited to 1 or 2 records.

Is there a better way of doing this?

```
-- Apprroach1 - Weird WHERE clause
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#list') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #list

create table #list(Id int)
insert into #list(id) values (726), (712), (725)

declare @listCount int
select @listCount = count(*) from #list

select * from SalesLT.Product p
where 1 = 1
AND 
    (
        @listCount > 0 AND p.ProductID in (select Id from #list)
        OR
        @listCount = 0
    )
```

and

```
-- approach 2 - goofy looking JOIN

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#list') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #list

create table #list(Id int)
insert into #list(id) values (726), (712), (725)

declare @listCount int
select @listCount = count(*) from #list

select * from SalesLT.Product p
inner join #list l on 
    case when @listCount > 0 and l.Id = p.ProductID Then 1
    else 0
    end = 1
```

Comment: When checking for the existence of one or more rows it is more efficient to use [`exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) rather than getting an exact [`count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and then just checking if it is greater than zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, `case when` in joins (`ON` clause) are avoided as it will make less performant query.

Use the `left join` approach as follows:

```
select * from SalesLT.Product p
Left join #list l on l.Id = p.ProductID 
Where ( (@listCount > 0 and l.id is not null) 
        or @listCount = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```sql
IF @listCount > 0
BEGIN
   SELECT
      * 
   FROM SalesLT.Product p
   ------------------------
   INNER JOIN #list l ON 
   ------------------------
      l.Id = p.ProductID
   ------------------------
END
-- I assume you want to output everything if @listCount = 0
ELSE IF @listCount = 0
BEGIN
   SELECT
      * 
   FROM SalesLT.Product p
END
```

If you have a bunch of joins using that table outputs, you can store the output and use it on your real join/query.

Example:

```
IF @listCount > 0
BEGIN
   SELECT 
      * 
   INTO #TempSalesTbl 
   FROM SalesLT.Product p
   ------------------------
   INNER JOIN #list l ON 
   ------------------------
      l.Id = p.ProductID
   ------------------------
END
-- In your query
SELECT
  *
FROM Table A
INNER JOIN #TempSalesTbl  ON
   ...
```

Comment: That works, but requires me to duplicate the query which is much longer than the examplee.